# Issue with comparing 2 objects

Tags: javers

I have 2 objects to be compared, when the first object contains a newly added element, after compare the two object difference should be showing one as difference.

i.e., object 1 as 3 data elements in the list, object 2 as 3 data elements in the list, now for object 1 a new elemts is added to the first position, when comparing it should have returned in the difference only the newly added elements, but all 3 elements shows as changed and last one as added.

Seems when index is changed the issue is appearing

Example below :

Original List
1
2
3
Modified List
0
1
2
3

Actual Result :
Value Changes as  1 -> 0  ,2 -> 1, 3 -> 2
Newly Added as  3

Expected Result
Newly added 0

, i tried with latest version javers-4.0.0-RC3, still same result .

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to your question is the Javers doc
https://javers.org/documentation/diff-configuration/#list-algorithms